# MVC 4 - jQuery and Required Fields

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am really new to this, so I'm sure if this is the best way of doing something like this.  Basically, I have a search page.  The page contains two dropdowns, one selects what to search in(e.g. Device Name, Interface Name, etc.) and the other is used to select the search operators (e.g. "starts with", "contains", "equal to").  I figured I better start looking at jquery, as well as used in MVC built in validaton.  This led me to make all my fields required in my Model.

I also took the approach of putting a Text Box for each type of search item and hiding all the text boxes except the one that corresponds to the selected item in the "SearchIn" dropdown.

This all works fine, however, because each text box has validation enabled, if I don't put anything in the default selected option in SearchIn dropdown ("Device Name"), and I choose to select "Interface Name", which then devices the "DeviceName" TextBox, and shows the "InterfaceName" textbox, type a value in "InterfaceName" text box and press search, it doesn't go anywhere because even though the other text boxes are hidden, they still require a value in them.

How can I disable validation for particular elements that are hidden?

All my fields in my model are declared as [Required]:

```
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Device ID")]
    public int DeviceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Interface ID")]
    public int InterfaceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "InterfaceDeviceId")]
    public int InterfaceDeviceId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name="Device")]
    public string DeviceName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Interface")]
    public string InterfaceName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "MAC Address")]
    public string MACAddress { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IPv4 Address")]
    public string IPv4Address { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "IPv4 Subnet Mask")]
    public string IPv4SubnetMask { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "CIDR Notation")]
    public string CIDR { get; set; }
```

My View looks like this:

```
@model FindDevice.Models.DeviceInterfaceModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Index";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[type=text]').hide();
    var selectedOption = $('#SearchIn').find(':selected').val();
    $('#' + selectedOption).show();
    $('.field-validation-valid').hide();

    $('#SearchIn').change(function () {
        var selectedOption = $('#SearchIn').find(':selected').val();
        $('input[type=text]').hide();
        $('#' + selectedOption).show();
    });
});
</script>

<h2>Define your Search Query</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm("PerformSearch", "Search", FormMethod.Post))
{
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

@Html.DropDownList("SearchIn")
@Html.DropDownList("SearchOperators");

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.DeviceName);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.DeviceName)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.InterfaceName);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.InterfaceName)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.MACAddress);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.MACAddress)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IPv4Address);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IPv4Address)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.IPv4SubnetMask);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.IPv4SubnetMask)

@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.CIDR);
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CIDR)

@Html.TextBox("SearchString")
<input type="submit" value="Search" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a hidden input will still be validated, but if you disable an input it is not validated.

```
  // DISABLE AND HIDE
  $("#").prop('disabled', true);
  $("#").hide();

  // ENABLE AND SHOW
  $("#").prop('disabled', false);
  $("#").show()
```

Try something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can disable any control to prevent them being validating by jquery. But by doing this, you wont be able to post disabled fields in a form by submitting it.

If you won't need to post them to the controller you can disable them like @BRomine already answered.

```
$("selector").hide().prop('disabled', true);
```

---

If you still want to send them to the controller, you can remove them from jquery validator.

To remove them you can use `ignore` option.
You can check the code below for preventing hidden inputs being validated:

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    ignore: ":hidden"
});
```

Or you can even ignore them by adding classes...

```
$("#myForm").validate({
    ignore: ".ignore"
});

$("selector").hide().addClass('ignore');
```